# Animation slide CSS aligning trouble

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've made a 4 slide animation of text, that goes from right to left, but I cannot seem to understand how to fix this width and height error.
I want the text to always be in the middle of the slides, but if you expand or scrunch your browser, it gets lost.

There's obviously a problem with the width and height, but I cannot seem to find the proper ratio that will always keep the text in the middle, no matter how you manipulate the browser window size.

The code is below:

```css
.frame{
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slidewrapper{
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: slideshow 24s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  position: relative;
   left: 30px;
   top: -150px;
}
.slide{
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 4%;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.p1{
  background-color: hotpink;
}
.p2{
  background-color: blue;
}
.p3{
  background-color: teal;
}
.p4{
  background-color: green;
}
@keyframes slideshow {
  0%{margin-left: -10%  }
  25%{margin-left: -100% }
  50%{ margin-left: -200% }
  75%{margin-left: -300%  }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
    <div class="slidewrapper">
      <div class="slide p1" style="color: blue">
        Free shipping and handling on order over $50. CODE:<i>FREE50</i>
      </div>
      
      <div class='slide p2'>  <p> Summer Sale </p>
        <b> Starting Soon!</b>
        <i>Exceptions apply</i>
      </div>
      
      <div class='slide p3'> <p> Summer Sale </p>
        <b> Starting Soon!</b>
        <i>Exceptions apply</i>
      </div>
      
      <div class='slide p4'><p> Summer Sale </p>
        <b> Starting Soon!</b>
        <i>Exceptions apply</i>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to word it, but there's a problem where the text doesn't align with the animation if you expand or shrink your browser window. It's only correctly placed at a fixed position. So I assumed it's a height/width problem, but it could be called something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a fixed `padding-top` instead of a percentage, where the padding is determined by a unit instead of the screen's dimensions:

```css
    .frame{
      border: 2px solid red;
      height: 80px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .slidewrapper{
      border: 2px solid blue;
      width: 400%;
      height: 100%;
      animation: slideshow 24s;
      animation-iteration-count:infinite;
      position: relative;
       left: 30px;
       top: -150px;
    }
    .slide{
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
      width: 25%;
      float: right;
      padding-top: 150px;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
    .p1{
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
    .p2{
    background-color: blue;
    }
    .p3{
    background-color: teal;
    }
    .p4{
    background-color: green;
    }
    @keyframes slideshow {
      0%{margin-left: -10%  }
      25%{margin-left: -100% }
      50%{ margin-left: -200% }
      75%{margin-left: -300%  }
      }
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class='frame'>
    <div class="slidewrapper">
      <div class="slide p1" style="color: blue">Free shipping and handling on order over $50. CODE:
        <i>FREE50</i></div>
      <div class='slide p2'>
        <p> Summer Sale </p>
        <b> Starting Soon!</b>
        <i>Exceptions apply</i></div>
      <div class='slide p3'>
        <p> Summer Sale </p>
        <b> Starting Soon!</b>
        <i>Exceptions apply</i></div>
      <div class='slide p4'>
        <p> Summer Sale </p>
        <b> Starting Soon!</b>
        <i>Exceptions apply</i></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @anatolhiman Why would you need top padding to scale flexibly to viewport size? The container has a fixed height that doesn't scale.

Comment: @Spectric You misunderstood. I said you don't need top padding. Your solution uses a fixed top padding which isn't a good solution in order to center the content in a box.

Comment: @anatolhiman If the container had a flexible size dependent on viewport height, then sure. However, the height is fixed, so using a fixed padding is the simplest viable solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would use flex for this. I have trimmed down your code a bit and added flex. You need to adjust the slide height so it has enough space for your content.

I didn't add any padding, so make sure you add a general padding to your slides (not only a top padding) so that it looks nice when the text hits the edges of your slide containers.

Notice the flex-direction column, which makes your text elements stack vertically like you probably want it to be, even if the slide has flex applied to it.

If you want all the text on the same line, just remove that line of css and it will be sorted out.

```css
.frame{
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slidewrapper{
  display: flex;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: slideshow 24s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
.slide{
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.p1{
  background-color: hotpink;
}
.p2{
  background-color: blue;
}
.p3{
  background-color: teal;
}
.p4{
  background-color: green;
}
@keyframes slideshow {
  0%{margin-left: -10%  }
  25%{margin-left: -100% }
  50%{ margin-left: -200% }
  75%{margin-left: -300%  }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
    <div class="slidewrapper">
      <div class="slide p1" style="color: blue">
        Free shipping and handling on order over $50. CODE:<i>FREE50</i>
      </div>
      
      <div class='slide p2'>  <p> Summer Sale </p>
        <b> Starting Soon!</b>
        <i>Exceptions apply</i>
      </div>
      
      <div class='slide p3'> <p> Summer Sale </p>
        <b> Starting Soon!</b>
        <i>Exceptions apply</i>
      </div>
      
      <div class='slide p4'><p> Summer Sale </p>
        <b> Starting Soon!</b>
        <i>Exceptions apply</i>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking about using flex also. I will try that next time.